# How I create a pool thread to will execute task in background

Tags: android

I want create a thread pool to will execute tasks (for example tasks that save in sharedprefences some data) but I don't know how I might do this with a pool thread. In android exists the threadpoolexecutor class but this class is very simple. I want other library that manage that tasks in a queue or something like this.

Do they know a library or anything that do this?

Thanks!

Comment: For shared preferences use apply() instead of commit()

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for that, all `AsyncTask`s are run in a FIFO queue (but can be executed paralelly).